# Take snap shot - only part of UIView, not the whole frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I can take snapshots of the whole frame of the UIView with no problem.
Taking part of it cause to a squeezed image.

This is my UIView category method:

```
- (UIImage *)snapshot:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

And this is the call to this method:

```
UIImage *img = [self.view snapshot:bottomRectToSnap];
```

When bottomRectToSnap is a partial frame of the view.

Note:The UIView contains UITableView if that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are applying is fine.

Need to add some logic, whatever part you need to take snap, It should be available on screen and hide rest of part while snapping.

Once snap shot done, remove hide code. So it will not effect to view interface too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
- (void)captureView:(UIView*)view withFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGRect rect = frame;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to take the snapshot of particular part..

```
    CGRect cropRect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([_galleryimageview.image CGImage], cropRect);

    UIImage *cropedImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

This code crop the part of particular image ...Hope this is helpfull for you..